# PHP - Get values of image URLS outside foreach?

Tags: php

I have this php code to check whether an image exists or not.

```
foreach($pic_switch as $pic_switch_key => $pic_switch_value)
{
if ($pic_switch_value == "no-image")
{
$img_url = 'http://www.reuters.com/resources_v2/images/masthead-logo.gif';
}
else
{
$img_url = $img_location . $pic_switch_key . '.jpg';
}
}
```

The above code works great.

I would like to echo $img_url outside the foreach. I tried:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($img_url,true).'</pre>';
```

but it only gives the URL of the last image. I would like to display the URL of all the images. I would like to display all of them outside the Foreach, rather than echo the URL inside it.

Comment: Why, what's wrong with the foreach? The only way around it would be adding all the URLs to an array ... which you would then again have to walk through using e.g. foreach. (Or you could add it to a giant string, but to what end really?)

Comment: I would prefer it outside the foreach - for various reasons because of the aim I am tryint to achieve.

Comment: maybe you should explain some more what you're trying to do. Right now, this request makes no sense. How else would you deal with multiple elements than in some kind of loop?

Comment: I would like to display an the uploaded image next to an upload image text box. and I'd like to have the image displayed next to the upload image textbox after it is uploaded, and I do not wish to inporcoprate the upload image input in the foreach.

Comment: That should be easy to do - but how to do it depends on the details of how you render those uploaded image inputs. In its current state, we can't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `foreach` this way, you will end up storing the last variable only in the `$img_url`. So use this way:

```
foreach ($pic_switch as $pic_switch_key => $pic_switch_value)
{
    if ($pic_switch_value == "no-image")
    {
        $img_url = 'http://www.reuters.com/resources_v2/images/masthead-logo.gif';
    }
    else
    {
        $img_url = $img_location . $pic_switch_key . '.jpg';
    }
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($img_url, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Though I wish to echo the $img_url outside the foreach. How can this be done?

Comment: Then you need a long string. Instead of this line: `$img_url = $img_location . $pic_switch_key . '.jpg';`, use `$img_url .= $img_location . $pic_switch_key . '.jpg';`

Comment: The image URLS displayed but prior to that it told me - Undefined variable: img_url

Comment: The image URLS displayed but prior to that it told me - Undefined variable: img_url - but img_url is defined. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you can't echo from within a loop but one method would be to build a string within the loop and echo it later in the script.

It would be neater to build an array of the URLs and echo from within a for loop later.